# Pass a byte array to Android plugin in Unity3D C# script

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am trying to write an Android plugin (.aar) for Unity3D and pass a byte array out of C# to a Java method, which is supposed to fill it with data.

```
//C# code:
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int bytesRead = myJavaObject.Call<int>( "read", buffer );
//buffer contains only zeros
```

```
//Java code:
public int read( byte[] buffer )
{
    //fill buffer here...
    return numOfBytesRead;
}
```

What I get in my logcat is this:

> 2020-02-12 16:41:22.717 23831-23855/? W/Unity: AndroidJNIHelper.GetSignature: using Byte parameters is obsolete, use SByte parameters instead 
>       (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

When I use `sbyte[]` instead of `byte[]` in my C# code instead, the warning disappears, but the array, contains only zeros, after calling read. I doublechecked, the array content is correct in Java.

Comment: What is your scripting backend?

Comment: Mono with API Compatibility Level .NET 4.x